# Open a file from ftp server in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, ftp

I have a button in my C# project. When it is clicked, it must show a file that is on an FTP server. For example, there is an file with name image.jpg in ftp://myftp/myftpfolder.

I know how download this file. Is there a way to show that file when clicking the button without store it in local?

Comment: No. Download first, then open it.

Comment: How are you showing the image? Somehow it always must be downloaded, but some controls accept a URI and do the download internally...

Comment: @ChrFin . if file is'nt in ftp , I use this code:

Comment: Process prc = new Process();
redfileName = ImagePath;
prc.StartInfo.FileName = ImagePath;
redProcces = prc;
prc.Start();

Comment: Obviously the data for the file has to be on your computer for the image to be displayed so you have no choice but to download it from that point of view. That doesn't mean that you have to save the downloaded data to a file though. If you want to open the image in an external application then you do have to save a file but if you want to open it in your own application then you can use the `Image.FromStream` method to create an `Image` object from the response stream of an `FtpWebRequest`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I dont know how. can you write it in answers for me ?

Comment: Do some research, make an attempt and if it doesn't work, post here and show us what you've done and where you're stuck.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I try this code :  
                ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
                ftpReq.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftpUserid, ftpPassWord, ftpDomain)
           Dim FTPResp As FtpWebResponse = ftpReq.GetResponse
                Dim ftpRespStream As Stream = FTPResp.GetResponseStream
                Dim file As System.Drawing.Image = Image.FromStream(ftpRespStream)                                                                                    but I haven't image file. I have file with different types. Now I dont know how can i open it ?

Comment: Code that is more than one short line is basically unreadable in a comment.  Please edit your question and format the code so that is readable and provide any additional relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by without download? I think you're trying to say without storing data in local system:

```
WebClient req = new WebClient();
string url = "ftp://myftp/myftpfolder" + "yourfilename";
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("  ", " ");
try
{
    byte[] FData = req.DownloadData(url);
    string fString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(FData);
    Console.WriteLine(fString);
}
catch (WebException e)
{
}
```

Comment: yes i mean without storing data in local system.  but this code is not work .  in line  Console.WriteLine(fString); it stoped.

Comment: make sure url is available and file have utf-8 encoding. console.writeline use to print data in console.

Comment: I sure because I can store the file. but I dont know how open the file withoit sotre it

Comment: in the above example FData hold file in Byte Format, now You can convert in what ever format you want, you havent need to store it locally your problem solved!

Comment: can u explain how can i change the format. for example if file is pdf or image ?

Comment: create object of the particular format you want then use casting/conversion to convert from binary to particular that format.